# How to change a single tag with xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing, saxon

In the result below, `OrderDetail` has been replaced with `baz`.  How would a similar `xslt` change only the first occurrence of `OrderDetail` and no other occurrences?

Using `saxonb-xslt` the current result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order OrderID="10613">
  <CustomerID>HILAA</CustomerID>
  <EmployeeID>4</EmployeeID>
  <OrderDate>1997-07-29T05:38:16</OrderDate>
  <RequiredDate>1997-08-26T11:38:15</RequiredDate>
  <ShippedDate>1997-08-01T12:46:12</ShippedDate>
  <ShipVia>2</ShipVia>
  <Freight>8.1100</Freight>
  <ShipName>HILARION-Abastos</ShipName>
  <ShipAddress>Carrera 22 con Ave. Carlos Soublette #8-35</ShipAddress>
  <ShipCity>San Cristóbal</ShipCity>
  <ShipRegion>Táchira</ShipRegion>
  <ShipPostalCode>5022</ShipPostalCode>
  <ShipCountry>Venezuela</ShipCountry>
  <OrderDetails>
      <baz>
         <ProductID>13</ProductID>
         <UnitPrice>6.0000</UnitPrice>
         <Quantity>8</Quantity>
         <Discount>0.1</Discount>
      </baz>
      <baz>
         <ProductID>75</ProductID>
         <UnitPrice>7.7500</UnitPrice>
         <Quantity>40</Quantity>
         <Discount>0</Discount>
      </baz>
  </OrderDetails>
</Order>
```

from this [snippet](https://gist.github.com/NICKSAUNDERS/2a1a9de15e2b52de6fd89642379d7342) of a larger `xml` file:

```
<Order OrderID="10613">
  <CustomerID>HILAA</CustomerID>
  <EmployeeID>4</EmployeeID>
  <OrderDate>1997-07-29T05:38:16</OrderDate>
  <RequiredDate>1997-08-26T11:38:15</RequiredDate>
  <ShippedDate>1997-08-01T12:46:12</ShippedDate>
  <ShipVia>2</ShipVia>
  <Freight>8.1100</Freight>
  <ShipName>HILARION-Abastos</ShipName>
  <ShipAddress>Carrera 22 con Ave. Carlos Soublette #8-35</ShipAddress>
  <ShipCity>San Cristóbal</ShipCity>
  <ShipRegion>Táchira</ShipRegion>
  <ShipPostalCode>5022</ShipPostalCode>
  <ShipCountry>Venezuela</ShipCountry>
  <OrderDetails>
    <OrderDetail>
      <ProductID>13</ProductID>
      <UnitPrice>6.0000</UnitPrice>
      <Quantity>8</Quantity>
      <Discount>0.1</Discount>
    </OrderDetail>
    <OrderDetail>
      <ProductID>75</ProductID>
      <UnitPrice>7.7500</UnitPrice>
      <Quantity>40</Quantity>
      <Discount>0</Discount>
    </OrderDetail>
  </OrderDetails>
</Order>
```

with this `xslt` transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>


<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OrderDetail">
    <baz>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </baz>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this changes all matching node names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `<OrderDetail>` is the one that has no `<OrderDetail>`s before it.

```
<xsl:template match="OrderDetail[not(preceding::OrderDetail)]">
    <baz>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </baz>
</xsl:template>
```

This matches the first in the entire document, regardless of nesting.

Depending on how you define "first", there are other options, e.g. `match="OrderDetail[1]"`, which matches the first *within its respective parent element*.

Comment: and `match` is in xslt 3 but not 2?  And, yes, I'm probably defining "first" as more `OrderDetail[1]` with a sort of relative xpath (?).

Comment: @NicholasSaunders *"`match` is in xslt 3 but not 2?"* - `match` has always been there, not sure what you mean. Also *"sort of relative xpath (?)"* is unclear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: my misunderstanding, then as I thought that `match` was new for `xslt` 3.  The question is somewhat vague in terms of the location of `OrderDetail` in the tree:  which node is it's parent, etc.  Using the the `not(proceeding()` certainly makes sense.

Comment: @Nicholas The match expression *can* specify the location in the tree, but it does not need to. If just `match="OrderDetail[1]"` is given, any first `<OrderDetail>` in any element is matched. If `"OrderDetails/OrderDetail[1]"` is given, any first `<OrderDetail>` in any `<OrderDetails>` is matched, but it does not make assumptions about where that `<OrderDetails>` is. And so on. This does works differently from XPath in other places, which always refers to a context element unless it is an absolute path.